# How to read video urls alone from a website using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need to read all the video urls from a website.How to read it using the HtmlAgilityPack. I have tried it like this but it is not working.Here is my code

```
  var document = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.example.com/");
  var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img[src$='.mp4']")
             .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
             .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var urls = document.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("img")
    .Where(d => d.Attributes["src"].Value.EndsWith(".mp4"))
    .Select(d => d.Attributes["src"].Value);
```

From all `img` tags, only those with `src` value ending in `mp4` are considered.

Comment: No its not working. am reading a youtube video from this page http://www.volvocars.com/us/cars/new-models/s60

Comment: I have accessed the provided URL -> view source -> could not find anything that contains mp4. If the element is loaded asynchronously, it will not be available when fetching the document.